# How to find the period that most number of calls made where made from a file

Tags: java

I need to create a java project with the following:
I have an input file that holds calls range in milliseconds all over the year – the file is sorted by start time.
for example 
0-100 (call started at 0 ended at 100)
1-100 ,
5-50 ,
60-150,
65-180
I need to return the period in the year when the network was the busiest.
in this example the result will be 65-100 because in this period there were 4 calls in the air
I have limited heap memory ( 8GB ) and must run over the file only once
what is the best logic to use here ( in java)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to approach this problem would be to define the smallest unit of call. For example in the given situation, you can say that 1 millisecond is the smallest unit of call. Now you start with an array type of data structure that contains one cell for each unit of time. In the given example you have values from 0 to 180, so we will have an array of length 181, starting from 0 to 180.
Now as you encounter the calls, you can start incrementing the relevant cells. For example, when you see a call 0-100, you will increment cells 0 through 100. Similarly, you go through each of the calls. For efficiency sake, you can also cache indexes to largest counts so that you can quickly reach to them.
In your example, the array would look like below.

12222333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
   32222222223333344444444444444444444444444444444444
   42222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
   2111111111111111111111111111111

Here is a sample of c++ code that could compute above array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <climits>

struct Call {
  Call(int start, int end) {
    this->start = start;
    this->end = end;
  }
  int start;
  int end;
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  const Call calls[] = { Call(0, 100),
             Call(1, 100),
             Call(5, 50),
             Call(60, 150),
             Call(65, 180)};
  int minimum = INT_MAX;
  int maximum = INT_MIN;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(calls)/sizeof(calls[0]); ++i) {
    minimum = std::min(minimum, calls[i].start);
    maximum = std::max(maximum, calls[i].end);
  }
  int *ongoingCalls = new int[maximum + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(calls)/sizeof(calls[0]); ++i) {
    for (int j = calls[i].start; j <= calls[i].end; ++j) {
      ++(ongoingCalls[j]);
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < maximum + 1; ++i) {
    if (i % 50 == 0) {
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << ongoingCalls[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you but that is not the solution I am looking for since the file holds all the calls made in 1 year meaning i have 31 milliards units to manageand. this would be too much on the memory...

Comment: You can probably write the whole array to a file and only keep those fragments that are showing top times. Also, one way to minimize what you really need to keep in memory would be to sort the incoming data by timestamp. That way things that are not in top times can be flushed back to the disk.